# use MapQuest javascript sdk in android

Tags: javascript, android, dictionary

I want to use a maps apart from a google maps in my android application , now i want to use MapQuest and it doesn't have a MapQuest Android SDK ( they have java sdk but its being deprecated) , so eventually MapQuest has JavaScript SDK.

So can anyone tell me how can i use this javascript sdk in android so that i can use the maps of MapQuest and at the same time i can use native controls of android.

*Note: The reason i am shifting from google maps to MapQuest is , google map only shows traffic data as an overlay they don't return any traffic data or meta data like severity , incidents etc.*

Comment: MapQuest is still alive?

Comment: Well , i guess it is alive !! or what others options do i have for traffic data ?

Answer (score 1):

Mapquest's new Android SDK (beta) is here:

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/beta/android

and their traffic web-service, which can be called out to is here:

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/traffic-ws